# Sum column in the same hour together. If there is no record for that hour, store value as 0

Tags: sql, database, bigdata, presto

I am using PrestoDB and need to Sum column in the same hour together and if there is no record for that hour, store value as 0

I have this table:

```
Date                    |Instances
2015-10-12 06:15:00.000 |2   
2015-10-12 06:45:00.000 |5
2015-10-12 04:15:00.000 |2
2015-10-12 04:25:00.000 |3
2015-10-12 03:15:00.000 |5
2015-10-12 02:15:00.000 |6
2015-10-12 01:15:00.000 |6
```

I need this output:

```
     TIMEHOUR | INSTANCESUM
     6        | 7
---> 5        | 0 <---
     4        | 5
     3        | 5
     2        | 6
     1        | 6
```

How could I do this? I have found some information regarding using a temporary table. How can I do that in Presto db? The answers are not clear to me in other posts and are for MySQL. Would the same thing work for me?

Is there any Basic SQL way that I can do this? Seems like a common simple thing that people would need to use.

Comment: GROUP your result by extracted hour from your `Date` column and `sum()` the Instances.

Comment: @ConsiderMe, that won't give him instancesum for non-existing timehour which is the requirement

Comment: @Harsh agreed, OP needs to generate hours of dates and then LEFT JOIN to it.

Comment: how do i generate hour dates that is my biggest question. I am new to SQL

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create an Hours table (You only do this the once)

Insert 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ... 24

Then LEFT JOIN to your main table like this ...

```
SELECT HoursTable.Hour, SUM(MainTable.Hour)
FROM HoursTable
LEFT JOIN MainTable
ON HoursTable.Hour = MainTable.Hour
GROUP BY HoursTable.Hour
```

If the Hour is a part of a date field you'll have to pull out the Hours part of the column.

The LEFT JOIN will return all records in the HoursTable along with any matching records in the Main Table. So for your example above you'll be returned a Sum of 0 for Hour 5.

Create Table Example ...

```
CREATE TABLE Hours (Hour INT);

INSERT Hours VALUES (0);
INSERT Hours VALUES (1);
INSERT Hours VALUES (2);
INSERT Hours VALUES (3);
INSERT Hours VALUES (4);
INSERT Hours VALUES (5);
INSERT Hours VALUES (6);
INSERT Hours VALUES (7);
INSERT Hours VALUES (8);
INSERT Hours VALUES (9);
INSERT Hours VALUES (10);
INSERT Hours VALUES (11);
INSERT Hours VALUES (12);
INSERT Hours VALUES (13);
INSERT Hours VALUES (14);
INSERT Hours VALUES (15);
INSERT Hours VALUES (16);
INSERT Hours VALUES (17);
INSERT Hours VALUES (18);
INSERT Hours VALUES (19);
INSERT Hours VALUES (20);
INSERT Hours VALUES (21);
INSERT Hours VALUES (22);
INSERT Hours VALUES (23);
```

Comment: my biggest question is how you create an Hours table? I am new to SQL, that which you left out is precisely the thing that I am not sure how to do for this problem.

Comment: Added Create Table Example